# Lost data after restore

Tags: sql-server, restore

I had an issue after backing up and restoring the DB's from server to server, We have since had some issues with missing information.  Is there a way at this point in time to know if the databases were restored fully? 
Are there log files anywhere?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If the restore completed, then the database was restored fully. What kind of backup did you take (show the code, or explain the steps if using a 3rd party tool or SSMS GUI)? How did you restore that database (show the code, or explain the steps)? What information was *missing*?

[This answer](https://serverfault.com/a/100513) and the link to Paul Randal's article will help explain how a full backup happens and should answer your *Are the log files anywhere* question, assuming you did a *Full* backup. You can, of course, do transaction log backups too. - [scsimon](https://dba.stackexchange.com/users/95107/scsimon)

I've seen cases where backup was done appending to the file and then restore was done from the first file (which is default) from that file. I.e., restoring not-the-latest-backup. Check using `RESTORE HEADERONLY`. - [tibor-karaszi](https://dba.stackexchange.com/users/151544/tibor-karaszi)